# Reading and writing a file using string buffers

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to read and write a text document and then perform operations on it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int WRITE(char *FILENAME, char *DATA)
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    ptr_file =fopen(FILENAME, "w");
    if (!ptr_file)
        return 1;
    fprintf(ptr_file,"%s", DATA);
    fclose(ptr_file);
    return  0;
}

char READ(char *FILENAME)
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    char buf[1000];
    char* ret="";
    ptr_file =fopen(FILENAME,"r");
    if (!ptr_file)
        return "FAIL\n";
    while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
        ret=strcat("%s",ret);
    fclose(ptr_file);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{   
    char* DAT = "lol";
    char* FILENAME = "output.txt";
    char* NEWDAT;
    int count=0;
    int max=10;

    while (count<max) {
        NEWDAT=READ(FILENAME);
        WRITE(FILENAME,strcat(DAT,NEWDAT));
        count++;
    }
    READ(FILENAME);
    return 0;
}
```

This is what the compiler says

```
gcc -Wall -o "filewrite" "filewrite.c" (in directory: /home/x/Documents/programming/C code)
filewrite.c: In function ‘READ’:
filewrite.c:22:3: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
filewrite.c:26:2: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
filewrite.c: In function ‘main’:
filewrite.c:38:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
Compilation finished successfully.
```

Then it throws me a Code 139/Segmentation Fault. I... seriously cannot begin to understand what's going on here; at the level i am at.

#

POST-ANSWERS EDIT:
FIXED CODE **WORKING**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // malloc

int WRITE(char *FILENAME, char *DATA)
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    ptr_file =fopen(FILENAME, "w");
    if (!ptr_file)
        return 1;
    fprintf(ptr_file,"%s", DATA);
    fclose(ptr_file);
    return  0;
}

char* READ(char *FILENAME)
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    char buf[1000];     
    char *ret = malloc(1); 
    int retsize = 1; 
    ret[0]='\0';
    buf[0]='\0';

    ptr_file = fopen(FILENAME,"r");
    if (!ptr_file) {
        ret = realloc(ret, strlen("FAIL\n") + 1);
        strcpy(ret, "FAIL\n");
        return ret;
    }
    while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
    {
        retsize += strlen(buf)+1;  // new size is old size + length of string in buf
        ret = realloc(ret, retsize);  // increase the size of the allocation
        strcat(ret, buf);          // append the new data
    }
    fclose(ptr_file);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{   
    char* DAT = malloc(1);
    int datsize = 1;
    char* FILENAME = "output.txt";
    char* NEWDAT; 
    strcpy(DAT, "LOL");
    int count=0;
    int max=5;

    while (count<max) {
        NEWDAT=READ(FILENAME);
        datsize += strlen(NEWDAT) + strlen(DAT);
        DAT = realloc(DAT, datsize);
        strcat(DAT,NEWDAT);
        WRITE(FILENAME,DAT);

        printf("%i\n",count);
        printf("%s\n",DAT); 
        count++;
    }
    READ(FILENAME);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`READ` (horrible naming convention BTW) claims to return a `char`, but your code is acting like it's `char*`

The `strcat("%s", ret)` is bad beacuse the destination ("%s") doesn't have any space to append "ret")

Comment: It should also be noticed that not only are you claiming to return a char from READ() and returning a char*, but the address pointed to by the char* you're returning will be destroyed when the function exits because it is not dynamically allocated. malloc() can save you from that headache.

Comment: Ok i see i was using strcat completely wrong. And brainsteel... thank you for making me realise i still haven't the farthest idea of how pointers work

Comment: @BrainSteel - good catch. Returning local vars is normally one of the first things I look for, guess there was too much other stuff going on.  The edited READ method now doesn't do any reading plus it's unclear whether you need to free() the results of READ - it can return string literals or malloced data and you can't tell them apart.

Answer (score 2):

This is the *big* problem I see.

```
char* ret="";
...
    ret=strcat("%s",ret);
```

For one, `strcat` doesn't take a format specification (maybe you're thinking of `sprintf`).

For two, you cannot modify the contents of a string literal (like `"%s"` or `""`). You have to allocate space or use a character array like you did with `buf`.

If you want to return the accumulated contents of `buf`, try

```
char *ret = malloc(1);
int retsize = 1;
ret[0] = '\0'; // this line could also be written: `strcpy(ret,"");` or `*ret = 0;`
...
while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
{
    retsize += strlen(buf)+1;  // new size is old size + length of string in buf
    ret = realloc(ret, retsize);  // increase the size of the allocation
    strcat(ret, buf);          // append the new data
}
```

To remove the compiler warnings, add

```
#include <stdlib.h>  // malloc
```

And, as others have said. The return type of the function should be `char *` to match the variable whose value is being returned.

---

*Addressing the edited code.*

NEWDAT is receiving the data read by READ. So it's DAT that needs to be resizable.

```
    ...
    char* DAT = malloc(1);
    int datsize = 1;
    char* FILENAME = "output.txt";
    char* NEWDAT; 
    DAT[0]='\0';
    int count=0;
    int max=5;

    while (count<max) {
        NEWDAT=READ(FILENAME);
        datsize += strlen(NEWDAT) + 1;
        DAT = realloc(DAT, datsize);
        strcat(DAT,NEWDAT);
        WRITE(FILENAME,NEWDAT);
        ...
```

---

As BrainSteel points out, there is another issue with the READ function, although it's not critical for getting this program to run.

```
if (!ptr_file)
    return "FAIL\n";
```

Since one path returns this string literal, and the other path returns `malloc`ed data, the calling function won't know whether to call `free` or not. We can fix this by always returning `malloc`ed memory.

```
if (!ptr_file) {
    ret = realloc(ret, strlen("FAIL\n") + 1);
    strcpy(ret, "FAIL\n");
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @luser droog I have included this into my code; it got rid of errors however the output of the file is simply "ÐÑlol". Clearly something failed? at the reading stage?

`code`
char* READ(char *FILENAME)
{
 FILE *ptr_file;
 char buf[1000];  
 char *ret = NULL;
 int retsize = 0;

 ptr_file =fopen(FILENAME,"r");
 if (!ptr_file)
  return "FAIL\n";
 {
     retsize += strlen(buf)+1;  // new size is old size + length of string in buf
     ret = realloc(ret, retsize);  // increase the size of the allocation
     strcat(ret, buf);
 }
 fclose(ptr_file);
 return ret;
}

`code`

EDIT: ...oh wow..

Comment: Oh. My fault. You have to have a string already there to use `strcat`. Try changing the declarations to `char *ret = malloc(1); int retsize = 1; ret[0] = '\0';`.

Comment: Oh. Added buf[0]='\0'; and now it does not read gibberish (have to have a string already there to use strcat). But nor does it read the file.

Comment: You've got another funky `strcat` in `main`. The destination needs to be an array or malloc'ed space, not a string literal.

Comment: Is it because READ returns a char*?
Posted complete code in edit; up

Comment: In `strcat(DAT,NEWDAT)`, `DAT` is the destination argument. It's the destination where the writing takes place, so that's where you need writable space. If you want to accumulate all the reads into DAT, then you'll need to use the same re-sizing idiom. Or a really big array.

Comment: Look above; i have no idea what just happened but i feel it might be bad. The writing part now seems to work 3 times until..???.

Comment: I've edited my answer. You just got them backwards (and didn't re-size). It blew up because you wrote past the end of the allocated memory in `NEWDAT` (née `ret`).

Comment: Alright that is in there. Since i think no additionnal input other than the file is there; i added text to the file. No more "you dun messed up" moment; however it seems to wipe the file clean every cycle whitout reading.. Code up in edit

Comment: You took out the `while(fgets(...))` line! I meant for you to leave that part and replace the single statement with the { compound statement }.

Comment: D'OH. Ok that is back where it is supposed to. Now it reads/writes a single iteration. Do i need a while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL) loop in the while (count<max) loop?

Comment: I'm hesitant to answer that because I'm pretty sure you can reason it out. What does `fgets` do? Do you need to do it there?

Comment: fgets reads data from a FILE stream, i do that in READ; nevermind i don't need it. Wait... if char* DAT = malloc(1); is my... ???... where is the data i am adding to the file? DAT was supposed to hold the data to add to the file

Comment: DAT is a pointer to malloc'ed memory that is being written to the file. It overwrites the contents of the file. If you want to just *add* more data to the file, then you can use "w+" as the mode argument to fopen.

Comment: Right now i see it reads the file then writes what it just read in it again; Oh ok. But i do want to overwrite it; only concentate the two strings of DAT and the file

Comment: If you add `DAT = "whatever";` then you change the pointer to point to the string literal "whatever". To copy the string "whatever" into DAT, you need to use a string function like `strcpy`. See the last part of my answer that deals with the "FAIL\n" string. And remember that malloc, realloc, and calloc all return a pointer to dynamically-allocated memory. The string literals live in a different part of memory that is usually marked READ-ONLY.

Comment: Added strcat(DAT, "whatever"); no change; tried strcpy(DAT, "whatever"); no change; tried removing DAT[0]='\0'; no change; tried char* DAT = "whatever"; code 139. I seriously need to read on the memory allocation because i have no idea why/what/where/when. This is my first program more advanced than 'hello world' and first time in a compiled language, so, yeah...

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want the program to *do*. ... Reading more is always good. ... The [info page for the C tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) has some good links. I'd recommend the comp.lang.c FAQ for lots of advice on working with dynamic memory and pointers.

Comment: My excuses. Basically i am trying to code a module that allows reading/writing files; i had it working perfectly in C++, even setup in a header file; but in C it seems everything is completely different and foreign

Comment: Yes, C and C++ are very different. You have to do manually a lot of things that C++ does for you. FWIW, I think you're doing just fine based on your level of knowledge. You might want to learn how to use a debugger so you can execute the program line-by-line and inspect the values of variables.

Comment: Indeed! Any lower level and it's Assembly. However; IT WORKS! I've found the problem. Thank you for you invaluable help!